# r.squared matrix of predictions vs actual values in R

Tags: r, matrix, syntax, statistics, coefficients

I want to create a matrix that displays the r.squared coefficient of determination of some predictions made over the years and the actual values.

My goal is to display a matrix that looks something like this.
[image: Matrix goal]

The only way I found is to make multiple lists, calculate each row/ column individually using `map2_dbl(l.predicted_line1, l.actual, ~ summary(lm(.x ~ .y))$r.squared)`, and then add the resulting vectors in a matrix with some code. This would create 9 lists, which I want to avoid.

Is there any way of doing this in a more efficiently?

```
#sample data
l.actual <- list(
    overall_15 = c(59,65,73,73,64,69,64,69,63,NA,82,60,NA,73,NA,73,73,NA,69,
                   69,71,66,65,70,72,72,NA,64,69,67,64,71,NA,62,62,71,67,63,64,76,72),
    overall_16 = c(60,68,75,74,68,71,NA,72,64,69,82,66,64,77,NA,71,72,NA,69,
                   69,75,67,71,73,73,73,NA,66,NA,69,65,70,76,NA,67,71,72,64,65,76,73),
    overall_17 = c(63,68,NA,74,72,72,NA,73,66,69,83,67,64,76,NA,71,73,NA,70,
                   70,79,NA,73,72,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,70,NA,70,77,NA,68,74,74,66,64,75,69),
    overall_18 = c(NA,68,NA,78,73,72,NA,72,68,67,86,NA,62,75,65,71,71,67,71,
                   71,76,NA,71,71,NA,NA,74,NA,71,NA,NA,68,74,NA,67,75,74,65,NA,72,NA),
    overall_19 = c(NA,NA,NA,77,73,72,NA,71,69,66,87,63,62,73,65,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                   NA,75,NA,NA,67,NA,NA,73,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,74,NA,NA,74,74,65,NA,68,NA),
    overall_20 = c(NA,NA,NA,77,NA,NA,NA,72,71,66,87,NA,NA,NA,65,NA,NA,NA,70,
                   70,75,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,74,NA,66,71,73,NA,NA,69,NA),
    overall_21 = c(NA,67,NA,76,NA,69,NA,73,69,65,85,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                   NA,75,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,69,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,73,NA,67,68,72,NA,NA,68,NA),
    overall_22 = c(NA,NA,NA,75,NA,NA,NA,75,67,65,84,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,68,
                   68,73,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,67,69,71,NA,NA,68,NA)
  )

l.predicted <- list(
  potential_15 = c(59,68,74,76,65,75,64,72,66,NA,85,60,NA,76,NA,73,75,NA,71,
                   71,71,67,65,70,72,72,NA,68,74,67,64,71,NA,62,62,71,71,63,67,78,72),
  potential_16 = c(60,71,75,75,68,73,NA,74,66,69,83,66,64,77,NA,71,74,NA,70,
                   70,76,67,71,73,73,73,NA,66,NA,69,65,70,76,NA,67,71,72,64,66,76,73),
  potential_17 = c(63,69,NA,75,72,72,NA,73,69,69,83,67,64,76,NA,71,73,NA,70,
                   70,79,NA,73,72,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,70,NA,70,77,NA,68,74,74,66,64,75,69),
  potential_18 = c(NA,68,NA,78,73,72,NA,72,69,67,86,NA,62,75,65,71,71,67,71,
                   71,76,NA,71,71,NA,NA,74,NA,71,NA,NA,68,74,NA,67,75,74,65,NA,72,NA),
  potential_19 = c(NA,NA,NA,77,73,72,NA,71,70,66,87,63,62,73,65,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                   NA,75,NA,NA,67,NA,NA,73,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,74,NA,NA,74,74,65,NA,68,NA),
  potential_20 = c(NA,NA,NA,77,NA,NA,NA,72,71,66,87,NA,NA,NA,65,NA,NA,NA,70,
                   70,75,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,74,NA,66,71,73,NA,NA,69,NA),
  potential_21 = c(NA,67,NA,76,NA,69,NA,73,69,65,85,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                   NA,75,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,69,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,73,NA,67,68,72,NA,NA,68,NA),
  potential_22 = c(NA,NA,NA,75,NA,NA,NA,75,67,65,84,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,68,
                   68,73,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,67,69,71,NA,NA,68,NA)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using some tidyverse packages. The key thing is to use the function `expand_grid()` to get all combinations of the elements of each list. This results in a tibble with two named list columns. Next we can use `mutate()` to pull out the names of the list and assign them to new columns, and extract the numeric IDs. Use `filter()` to retain only the rows where potential is less than or equal to overall. Finally get the R-squared for each row using your suggested code, and plot. (Note I did not try too hard to get the plot to look just like yours.)

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

r_squared_combinations <- expand_grid(l.actual, l.predicted) %>%
  mutate(overall = names(l.actual),
         potential = names(l.predicted),
         overall_n = as.numeric(gsub('overall_', '', overall)),
         potential_n = as.numeric(gsub('potential_', '', potential))) %>%
  filter(potential_n <= overall_n) %>%
  mutate(r_squared = map2_dbl(l.predicted, l.actual, ~ summary(lm(.x ~ .y))$r.squared))

ggplot(r_squared_combinations, aes(x = overall, y = potential, fill = r_squared, label = round(r_squared, 3))) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(color = 'white')
```

Side note: incidentally the base function `expand.grid()` would work about as well as `tidyr::expand_grid()` but `expand_grid()` returns a tibble by default which may be more convenient if you are using tidyverse functions otherwise.

[image]